# Embed fckeditor in java desktop app

Tags: java, swing, fckeditor

Can this be done? Or any other editors I can embed into my java swing app

Answer (score 1):

The DJ Native Swing project has several HTML editors, implemented using the SWT Browser (this is an implementation detail): http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns